# What's the best way to get the output of an script (shell-script) in Xulrunner?

Tags: shell, xul, xulrunner

I'm running a script with [nsIProcess.run()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIProcess#run%28%29), and the only way I found to get the output is to write the output to a file, and then read the file from javascript.

But for some reason, when I execute it from the xulrunner application, it does not generate the file with the output. Here's my function:

```
function runProcess() {
    // create an nsILocalFile for the executable
    var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces["nsILocalFile"]);
    file.initWithPath("/home/me/my-script.sh");

    write("FILE EXISTS = " + file.exists()); // it is printing TRUE, good!


    // create an nsIProcess
    var process = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
    process.init(file);

    // Run the process.
    // If first param is true, calling thread will be blocked until
    // called process terminates.
    // Second and third params are used to pass command-line arguments
    // to the process.
    process.run(true, [], 0);
}
```

**my-script.sh:**

```
echo ok > /tmp/result.txt
```

Is there a better (and working) approach to get this "ok" output from my-script.sh?

**--update**

I'm on Ubuntu 10.04 with Xulrunner 1.9.2.15

Comment: Try using an absolute path in your shell script. Its current directory may not be what you think it is.

Comment: So is the script getting executed, but the file is not written, or is the script not getting executed?  Can confirm that it does run in some way?

Comment: @Dennis Williamson good point. Unfortunately it's still not creating the file.

Comment: @pc1oad1etter actually, as it's not opening a terminal for me to see, I can't have sure it's executing.. But, now that you say, probably it's not even executing, something may be wrong with the javascript function..

Comment: Can you watch your process list and see if it gets kicked off there?

Comment: @pc1oad1etter looks like not, but I would be more sure if I know how to change the name of that process.. Also, there would be no sense if it runs and don't generate the file, becouse when I run it manually it generates the file. So it's 99% sure that it doesn't run.

Comment: Sounds like you have narrowed the scope of your problem some.  Can you use the same code to run some other file?  See if you can run some executable or something.

Comment: @pc1oad1etter I'm not sure if by calling `process.init("firefox");` it was supposed to start firefox, but nothing happened. By calling other `.sh` files don't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a third-party "ipc" library used e.g. by Enigmail that allows you to capture the output of a command. It might even become part of XULrunner at some point.

EDIT: As discussed in the comments, nsIProcess.run uses exec rather than system so the script needs to have a #! line so that the kernel can spawn the shell.

Comment: But, really looks like the script is not even running.. Any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried putting a sleep in your script to give yourself a chance to watch it run?

Comment: @Neil I put a sleep of 10 seconds and, as I don't know the name of the process, I call it to start 10 processes, but I noticed nothing new in the process manager. Either no process closed after the 10 seconds.

Comment: @Tom Brito OK, one last wild guess: have you tried starting your script with a #!/bin/sh (or whichever shell it needs) line and chmod +x?

Comment: Your last wild guess is right. A `#!/bin/bash` line solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: That line was never needed for me, my scripts run without it, until now. I think that, as I was calling from javascrip, my file was supposed to be a javascript file, until otherwise specified.

Answer (score 0):

From the discussion above, it sounds like the process may not be getting kicked off at all.

I would try two things

- Try calling some other process/executable
- change null to [], perhaps it is silently failing, expecting this to be an array (even if it is an empty array)

Comment: I've changed `null` for `[]`, but nothing changed. I'm not sure if by calling `process.init("firefox");` it was supposed to start firefox, but nothing happened also. By calling other `.sh` files don't work either.